# python schedule - jobs from python list

Tags: python, schedule

I'd like to use [python schedule library](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) to schedule a large amount of jobs.
All jobs perform the same operations but on a different input.
The inputs are stored in a python list.

The idea is to put each input from the list into a shared queue and then process each one of them in sequence.

Here is an example and my attempt:

```
import queue
import time
import threading
import schedule

def job(name):
    print(name)


def worker_main():
    while 1:
        (job_func,job_msg) = jobqueue.get()
        job_func(job_msg)
        jobqueue.task_done()


name = ['jane', 'alice', 'mary']
jobqueue = queue.Queue()

schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, (job, name))

worker_thread = threading.Thread(target=worker_main)
worker_thread.start()

while 1:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Unfortunately, this approach run 1 job for all items in the list all together.
Anyone has any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: Probably want something like this? `for n in name: schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, (job, n))`

Comment: Or do you want it too loop through the three names, doing a different one every two seconds?

Comment: flakes, thanks for taking the time helping me. 
Your suggestion is correct: it loops through each item in the list and prints it. However, I would like it to put each item of the list in a queue so that I can make use of different threads (if required).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing every name in each 2 second interval:

```
for n in name:
    schedule.every(2).seconds.do(jobqueue.put, (job, n))
```

```
[Second 2]: jane
[Second 2]: alice
[Second 2]: mary
[Second 4]: jane
[Second 4]: alice
[Second 4]: mary
```

Printing a single name in each 2 second interval and looping through the list:

```
from itertools import cycle
name_iter = cycle(name)
schedule.every(2).seconds.do(lambda: jobqueue.put((job, next(name_iter))))
```

```
[Second 2]: jane
[Second 4]: alice
[Second 6]: mary
[Second 8]: jane
[Second 10]: alice
[Second 12]: mary
```

> What if I do not want to use cycle but stop when the iterator has been consumed

Looks like you can raise `schedule.CancelJob` https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples.html#run-a-job-once

```
name_iter = iter(name)
def queue_name():
    try:
        jobqueue.put((job, next(name_iter)))
    except StopIteration:
        return schedule.CancelJob

schedule.every(1).seconds.do(queue_name)
```

Comment: What if I do not want to use cycle but stop when the iterator has been consumed? Thanks.

Comment: @iEriii posted an example. Seems straight forward enough.